# Old Peugeot brakes not working in rain

Tags: brakes, rims, vintage, peugeot

I have an old Peugeot bike that's pretty awesome but the brakes are bad. In good conditions they are weak, and when wet they stop working entirely. I wasn't sure what the issue was with this, and someone had recommended I buy entirely new rims.

Is there any way to make these brakes work in the rain without buying entirely new wheels? I like this bike, but I'm not looking to spend hundreds of dollars to restore it.

[image: Strange rim]

Comment: Have you put new brake pads on? Do that and clean the rims.

Comment: Do they work well when they are dry?

Comment: Are the rims made of steel?  Cos that's the lowest performing rim for braking when chromed.  Aluminium works much better, but that will not look "vintage"  Your rims appear to have a texture on them which should help with braking,

Comment: When did you last change the brake pads?  If they're hardened with age/ozone/UV then your braking experience will suffer.  I'd go for koolstop pads, which are available in traditional colours as well as their salmon/orange ones.

Comment: The brakes on your bike are Mafac centre pull brakes and the rims are steel, I had a similar Peugeot. New pads for this type of brake are quite hard to find. As @Criggie points out you may find them from koolstop. But in no case throw away the metal holders of the pads as they are almost impossible to come by. You'll have to buy the naked pads, slide the old ones out and the new ones in. Note carefully how the brake-arms and the pads are assembled and the position of the spacers and the spring.

Comment: @Carel does the imprint pattern on the brake track cause extra pad wear?

Comment: Do be aware that, with any rim brake bike, in the rain you will have difficulty for the first couple of seconds of braking.  The wheels need to turn 2-3 revolutions against the pads before brakes become effective, and even then effectiveness will be worse than with dry brakes.  Replacing the pads will help (the suggested Koolstop pads are a good idea) but pads of this style are hard to find.

Comment: @Criggie No, but it was imho a desperate attempt to make the brake track rougher in order to increase braking power. But since the rims were polished/chrome-plated they were also very 'slippery' and braking power tended towards zero when wet. The dimples held water through surface tension I think and did not improve drying. Aluminium rims are the only way to get real improvement

Comment: I'm not sure how old the brakes are, but I'll give the koolstop ones a try. If it doesn't work I'll look for some rims. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @bidart you can absolutely use the new brake pads on a replacement rim too.  Just remember modern road bike rims are 622mm  where this probably has "27 inch" wheels.  That could affect whether your brake arms reach the new rims, which are ~4mm smaller.  Also you can't move tyres between the two sizes of rim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three initial things to do are:

- Clean the rims, make sure they are free of anything that is acting as a lubricant. YOu may also consider carefully roughening them slightly with a fine grit sandpaper
- Get the best replacement brake pads you can
- Make sure the calipers are adjusted correctly and the pads are properly contacting the rim

Comment: make sure the bowden cables are freshly oiled and cleaned out

Comment: With steel rims braking is always problematic. The surface of the pads has to be absolutely parallel to the brake-track on the rim when seen from the front. The brake-shoes also need to be toed-in, i.e. the rear end slightly.closer to the rim when seen from above. This is even more important than on aluminium rims. It is a good idea to start braking early and learn to use both brakes properly. Real emergency braking with steel rims is always a gamble. On long descents keeping the pads close to the rims and applying the brakes slightly from time to time helps.

Comment: @Carel Ah, I didn't think the bike was old enough to have steel rims - explains why there was a recommendation to change them.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus: The low to midrange Peugeot around the 70s had this sort of steel rims with the 'file' pattern. And the Maillard Helicomatic freewheel system http://www.borgercompagnie.com/helicomatic/history.html .